# How to add new line as a separate element on a list?

Tags: python

I'm printing a variable my app is receiving and I get something like:

```
dog
cat
monkey
cow
```

I want to add this to a list as [dog,cat,monkey,cow] but I'm unsure how to get this as a list as its just all in a string variable (so when I do a for item in string:...I just get each letter separately and not the word). Is there a way to add each item to a list based on the fact that each item is a new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a built-in method of strings for this exact purpose called [`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

```
>>> tst = """dog
cat
monkey
cow"""
>>> tst
'dog\ncat\nmonkey\ncow'   # for loop gives you each letter because it's 1 string
>>> tst.splitlines()
['dog', 'cat', 'monkey', 'cow']
```

Now of course you can just append to it:

```
>>> lst = tst.splitlines()
>>> lst.append("lemur")
>>> lst
['dog', 'cat', 'monkey', 'cow', 'lemur']
```

Want it back as a multi-line string? Use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
>>> '\n'.join(lst)
'dog\ncat\nmonkey\ncow\nlemur'
>>> print '\n'.join(lst)
dog
cat
monkey
cow
lemur
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `str.splitlines`:

```
>>> mystr = "dog\ncat\nmonkey\ncow"
>>> print(mystr)
dog
cat
monkey
cow
>>> mystr.splitlines()
['dog', 'cat', 'monkey', 'cow']
>>>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

> `str.splitlines([keepends])`
>
> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries. This method uses the [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) approach to
>   splitting lines. Line breaks are not included in the resulting list
>   unless `keepends` is given and true.